# How to start the conversation with my neighbor

Tags: conversations, strangers, neighbors

I'm a boy in my twenties and I'm living in my parent's house in the north of France.

For more than one year we have new neighbors. Their daughter (who is about my age) is beautiful and I want to get in touch with her. Basically I'm looking for a friend, especially because I'm just going out of a relationship, but I find her very attractive and I will not be against a relationship with her if I find her interesting after we talked a little.

I actually know her name from the name of his parents, Facebook did the rest of the job.

I'm wondering how I can start the conversation. In fact I can't use the usual techniques like asking for some salt or oil because she is living in her parent's house too.

She is living two houses away so she is never passing in front of my house, and me neither. I'll never meet her naturally, I have to go ahead if I want to talk with her.

Actually I'm pretty shy and I would prefer to start the conversation through internet, but I think it's not the more efficient way to get in touch with a girl, it could looks weird to do it, especially for someone living so close to me.

But I'm not really comfortable with this kind of situation, I don't know what to ask or even how to engage the discussion. I know it's like any other girl I could meet in the street but I'm not used to start a conversation with a stranger and I'm pretty sure that I can turn in my advantage the fact that we are neighbors.

I don't know anything about her culture, in fact she hasn't distinctives signs, but in my case I'm an open-minded person and I'm not religious.

What the best way to start a conversation with her ?

Comment: perhaps some more about your neighborhood or activities could help get some answers. Does either your family or hers own pets that require walking? Perhaps your neighborhood has block party, barbecue or meet-and-greet event?

Comment: I have an elderly neighborhood so we haven't any meeting such as barbecue or party. Also we both haven't any pets to walk with